# Cannot delete JMS properties when sending message to queue

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

I´m sending a simple message using JMSTemplate and IBM queue manager.

```
public void sendSomething(String message) throws JMSException {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(""queue:///MYQUEUE?targetClient=1"","my message");
  }
```

I debugged on jms template library and I found that in the last method responsible to send message:

```
protected void doSend(MessageProducer producer,
                      Message message)
               throws JMSException

...
producer.send(message);
...
```

message has a lot of properties like JMSMessage, JMSType, JMSDeliveryMode.... and the body(my message).

How can I sent just body and delete all this properties?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot; that's how JMS works; read the spec.

If you are talking about IBM MQ RFH2 headers, and the consumer is a native MQ app (not JMS) see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031990_.htm).

> The MQRFH2 is optional, and its inclusion in an outgoing message is governed by the TARGCLIENT flag in the JMS Destination class. You can set this flag using the IBM MQ JMS administration tool. Because the MQRFH2 carries JMS-specific information, always include it in the message when the sender knows that the receiving destination is a JMS application. Normally, omit the MQRFH2 when sending a message directly to a non-JMS application. This is because such an application does not expect an MQRFH2 in its IBM MQ message.

I believe that means you will have to send to a `Destination` object rather than a destination name; with the destination having the property set:

```java
mqDestination.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
```

Comment: Ok. What you suggest for this particular case?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Just ignore the additional metadata on the consumer if you don't care about it.

Comment: I dont have access to consumer and apparently the consumer is parsing the whole message   like this : `<jms><queue>myque</queue>..</jms>my message` and I just him to parse my message

Comment: See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031990_.htm). `The MQRFH2 is optional, and its inclusion in an outgoing message is governed ... JMS Destination class. You can set this flag using the IBM MQ JMS administration tool. Because the MQRFH2 carries JMS-specific information, always include it in the message when the sender knows that the receiving destination is a JMS application. Normally, omit the MQRFH2 when sending a message directly to a non-JMS application. This is because such an application does not expect an MQRFH2 in its IBM MQ message`

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on target client - see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032240_.htm).

There are 3 ways to solve your problem:

(1) Use the setTargetClient method and MQ will strip all JMS headers (aka MQRFH2 headers) and only deliver the payload

```
conn = mqQCF.createQueueConnection("MyUserId", "mypwd");
conn.start();
session = conn.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
myQ = session.createQueue("my.test.queue");
MQDestination mqd = (MQDestination) myQ;
mqd.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
```

(2) Explicitly set the MQ queue name and target client (1 is for MQ & 0 is for JMS message) and MQ will strip all JMS headers (aka MQRFH2 headers) and only deliver the payload

```
conn = mqQCF.createQueueConnection("MyUserId", "mypwd");
conn.start();
session = conn.createQueueSession(true, 0);
queue = queueSession.createQueue("queue://MQA1/TEST.Q1?targetClient=1");
sender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
```

(3) Set the target client in the MQ JNDI and MQ will strip all JMS headers (aka MQRFH2 headers) and only deliver the payload

```
DEFINE Q(my.test.queue) QUEUE(TEST.Q1) QMANAGER(MQA1) TARGCLIENT(MQ) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting targetClient to indicate an MQ consumer, you could instead alter the queue on the IBM MQ queue manager to use `PROPCTL(NONE)`. This will mean that any consumers who specifically cannot handle the properties are not given them when they consume the message.

You don't say what type of application the consumer is.